# AVConv X11Grab Issues: Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pulse'

Tags: 12.04, pulseaudio, x11, ffmpeg

I am running **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-Bit**, and I am attempting to use **avconv** to record the primary display connected to my computer (**resolution of 1920x1080**) using **x11grab** at **30 frames per second**, along with audio from the default audio device connected to my computer through **pulse**.

However, when I run the command:

**`avconv -f x11grab -s hd1080 -r 30 -i :0.0 pulse -i default recording.ogv`**

the terminal prints out the error:

**`Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pulse'`**.

What is causing this error message to be displayed?

Answer (score 2):

avconv is assuming that your output is named "pulse", so you need to add some additional options to indicate that it is an input. I use ffmpeg from the FFmpeg project and not avconv from the fork so I'll use ffmpeg for my examples.

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s hd1080 -r 30 -i :0.0 -f pulse -i default recording.ogv
```

Unfortunately this won't work with avconv from the repository because it was not compiled with `--enable-libpulse` as far as I know. So instead you can try:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s hd1080 -r 30 -i :0.0 -f alsa -i pulse recording.ogv
```

If you find that you need to use `-f pulse` then you will have to compile. See [How To Compile FFmpeg and x264 on Ubuntu](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide) for a complete guide. You will need to additionally add `libpulse-dev` as a dependency and `--enable-libpulse` to the `configure` line. Also see [HOWTO: Proper Screencasting on Linux](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8746719#post8746719) for some good x11grab examples. It's for ffmpeg but should probably work for avconv.

Comment: Could you possibly clarify how to use ffmpeg on Ubuntu 12.04 becaues when I try to run an ffmpeg command, I get the message: This program is not developed anymore and is only provided for compatibility. Use avconv instead (see Changelog for the list of incompatible changes).

Comment: In 12.04 the `avconv` and `ffmpeg` binaries are from the same repository package and there is no difference other than the name. See [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017) for more details.